# Update a pandas dataframe with data from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got two similar DataFrames.

```
df1.head()
        1        2        3      4
3234    Lorum    Ipsum    Foo    Bar
8839    NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
9911    Lorum    Ipsum    Bar    Foo
2256    NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN

df2.head()
        1        3        4
8839    Lorum    Ipsum    Foo
2256    Lorum    Ipsum    Bar
```

I'd like to merge/update the two based on same index and column to update the NaN values.

Ideal outcome:

```
df3.head()
        1        2        3      4
3234    Lorum    Ipsum    Foo    Bar
8839    Lorum    NaN      Ipsum  Foo
9911    Lorum    Ipsum    Bar    Foo
2256    Lorum    NaN      Ipsum  Bar
```

`df2` doesn't contain all of the columns as `df1` but the columns it does contain match and it has matching indexes.

I've tried this:

```
df3 = df1.update(df2)
```

But haven't had any success. I've been looking at the docs and think `pd.merge` or `pd.concat` may help but I'm a bit confused.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1).reindex(df1.index)
print (df3)
          1      2      3    4
3234  Lorum  Ipsum    Foo  Bar
8839  Lorum    NaN  Ipsum  Foo
9911  Lorum  Ipsum    Bar  Foo
2256  Lorum    NaN  Ipsum  Bar
```

Or use your solution, but [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) working inplace, so if assign to variable it return `None`:

```
df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
          1      2      3    4
3234  Lorum  Ipsum    Foo  Bar
8839  Lorum    NaN  Ipsum  Foo
9911  Lorum  Ipsum    Bar  Foo
2256  Lorum    NaN  Ipsum  Bar

print (df1.update(df2))
None
```